# Create a Character Selector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my local Multiplayer game I want the players to choose between some characters. At the moment, the first player gets the first character and the second player the second character. I think I have to assign the Index to the player but how?

```
public class PlayerInputHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    Player player;


    [SerializeField] List<GameObject> prefrabs = new List<GameObject>();

    private void Start()
    {
        var playerIndex = GetComponent<PlayerInput>().playerIndex;
        player = GameObject.Instantiate(prefrabs[playerIndex], transform.position, transform.rotation).GetComponent<Player>();
    }
```

Comment: Where is the second player?

Comment: I not sure if you mean that but I have a PlayerInputManager which instantiates the Prefab "Player" when you press a button on a Controller. This "Player" has this script above. So when the first Player presses the button the "Player" instatiates the first Character of the List and when the second Player presses the button on another Controller it instatantiates the second Character in the List.
I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

if you want the player to choose their character,

```
public List<GameObject> characterList;
public int _selectedCharacterIndex = 0;
private Player _player;

private void Start()
{
   SelectCharacter(_selectedCharacterIndex);
}

private void SelectCharacter(int index)
{
  _player = Instantiate(characterList[index], transform.position, 
  transform.rotation).GetComponent<Player>();
}
```

In this way, you will give the character value you received from the player to the player, I hope I was able to help, I edited the code a little without forgetting, good luck

Comment: How do I give every character their own index or do I not understand something?

Comment: If you assign the players you created to a list and give the index of the list, each character will be taken once.